# Autocomplete callback method name without filling argument list in C++

Tags: c++, xcode, function-pointers

I am developing an application in C++ with Xcode, in which I have a number of callback functions that are passed via function pointer to numerous methods.

Xcode has a very useful feature wherein when you autocomplete a method name, it fills in little fields for each argument that you can tab through and replace. However, when I have a method which takes a function pointer as an argument, I just want to fill the method name and leave off the arguments. When the autocomplete sticks in all the arguments, I have to go through and delete each one as well as the commas, parens, etc.

Is there a way to hit option-return or something, to fill the complete method name without the rest of the signature filling in place?